# Magento getFirstItem and getLastItem not working on collection

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, collection

My code is as below but it won't work with loading first or last item.

```
    $shipidarr[0] = 100007536;

$shipModel = Mage::getModel('orderstatus/orderstatus')->getCollection();
    $shipModel->addFieldToFilter('shipment_incrementid', array(array('like' => $shipidarr[0].'%')))->getLastItem();
```

Comment: Do you get data by `var_dump($shipModel->getData())` after you get collection?

Comment: yes get whole collection.

Comment: Then I think below answer should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$shipModelCollection = Mage::getModel('orderstatus/orderstatus')->getCollection();
$shipModelCollection->addFieldToFilter('shipment_incrementid', array(array('like' => $shipidarr[0].'%')));

if($shipModelCollection->getSize()){
$lastItem = $shipModelCollection->getLastItem();

}
```

Comment: it's very strange.when i use `$shipModelCollection->getLastItem();` it won't work.but when i use with another variable define it works. like you did `$lastItem = $shipModelCollection->getLastItem();` how is this possible.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not getting result with `getFirstItem` or `getLastItem` on your collection is because they are function which return values. If a function returns data, then you must use a variable to store the returned value.
check `Varien_Data_Collection::getFirstItem()` in **lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection last item
 *
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
public function getLastItem()
{
    $this->load();

    if (count($this->_items)) {
        return end($this->_items);
    }

    return new $this->_itemObjectClass();
}
```

You can see in its details `@return Varien_Object` it returns `Varian_Object`.
As this function returns data, you have to use a variable to get returned data or it will give you full collection data with filter.
Thats why

```
$shipModel->addFieldToFilter('shipment_incrementid', array(array('like' => $shipidarr[0].'%')))->getLastItem();
```

will give you full collection with filtered data and

```
$lastItem = $shipModel->addFieldToFilter('shipment_incrementid', array(array('like' => $shipidarr[0].'%')))->getLastItem();
```

will give you last item by code `end($this->_items);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$shipModelCollection = Mage::getModel('orderstatus/orderstatus')->create()->addFieldToFilter('shipment_incrementid', array(array('like' => $shipidarr[0].'%')))->getLastItem();